# Infected before or after death

Tags: the-walking-dead

I was wondering if the anyone has seen the people in the Walking Dead eat meat from animals. Are all animals infected so they can't eat any of them after they kill it, or if they catch a fish they are good to go and can eat it without any casualties? The same with deer, cows and pigs? I don't remember seeing them eat on the farm, maybe eggs. I thought I saw a zombie horse or maybe it was just being attacked it never showed the aftermath.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question I do not actually recall any scenes where they eat freshly procured protein.

However it is highly unlikely that consuming animal meat after the outbreak would be any more dangerous than it was before the outbreak even if the animals were carriers since everyone is a carrier.

There are also scenes of at least implied animal consumption including the deer hunting incident before finding the farm and the raising of pigs at the prison.

Comment: On a really separate note, whered my rep go

Comment: On a more **spoilery** note (if you're pre-season 3) - whatever it is that causes people to turn, everyone is infected already anyway, so eating animal meat is relatively harmless.  (I believe the creators have gone on record stating that the reason a bite or scratch makes you turn faster is because *a rotting corpse is full of (regular) diseases* that kill you quickly, and then you turn after death as you would have anyway.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that in later seasons, we've seen them eat animals they've killed or found on the road.